# What is the difference between the two R.exe binaries found in the bin directory in Windows?

Tags: r, windows

The two binaries being compared are -

1. C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\x64\R.exe
2. C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe

I have tested that the first one is able to start in UNC paths (e.g. shown below), whereas if I use the second executable, it throws an error `CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories`.

I read [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installation), but they did not go into the details of the different binaries.

[image: Task scheduler example]

Comment: 1 = x64, 2 = x32.

Comment: I suspect this is R version independent & the latest version doesn't have 32 bit. I'm not sure that is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer lies in docs, just two sections further - https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Sub_002darchitectures

Relevant quote:

> For backwards compatibility there are executables R_HOME/bin/R.exe and R_HOME/bin/Rscript.exe: these will run an executable from one of the subdirectories, which one being taken first from the R_ARCH environment variable, then from the --arch command-line option10 and finally from the installation default (which is 32-bit for a combined 32/64 bit R installation).

You're correct, since version 4.2.0 there is no 32-bit built, so it shouldn't  really matter. However, I don't know why exactly the second executable throws the error you quoted. Using `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\x64\R.exe` seems to be more explicit anyway.